# Joomla 300 concurrent users

Tags: mysql, performance, joomla, webserver

I've an issue on a website made in Joomla 2.5 with Ja teline IV template
that has 300 concurrent user, 
it is a soccer magazine, so the article are updated often, 
also minute by minute during the match.

I've a server of 16gb ram and quad core processor, but the website freeze when 300 users are accessing to the website.

I've done all the frontend optimization, but, I the last optimization could be enable caching. 
My issues are: 
 - caching enabled also for logged in users 
 - caching timing, if I have that type of article, I can enable cache
   expiring to 1 minute? It is also a good option? Could optimize the performance.

Can you suggest me what to do? Other possible optimization?

Comment: I hear [nginx](http://nginx.org/) is less memory-bloated than Apache, though I don't know if that will help your case.

Comment: @WaleedKhan I already use nginx.

Comment: If you profile it from the user's end, is it the page or the assets that takes the longer time loading?

Comment: @WaleedKhan no, I've compressed all.

Comment: That is neither "page" nor "assets".

Comment: @WaleedKhan sorry I've not understood well the question.
It's the page that takes longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16gb should be enough to handle 300 concurrent users...smells to mysql server not fine tuned.
Run this script for you Mysql server

https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the bottleneck: processor? memory? disk? database? network?

After you find the issue, you have to choose the right solution: bigger processor, more memory, faster disk, db index, memory caching, network caching, etc etc